# `*': negative argument (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, sorting, flickr

I'm trying to sort in descending order an array of photo objects from Flickr API based on the number of comments(`count_comments`) of each photo. I'm using the following code.

```
def rank_photos(photos)
  photos.sort_by { |photo| photo.count_comments * -1 }
end
```

However I get the following error message.

> *': negative argument (ArgumentError)

Here is what the Array looks like

> [{"id"=>"38280904752", "owner"=>"131718287@N07",
>   "secret"=>"abe0b93180", "server"=>"4583", "farm"=>5,
>   "title"=>"IMG_3640", "ispublic"=>1, "isfriend"=>0, "isfamily"=>0,
>   "count_comments"=>"0", "tags"=>"washington post dc web women codeher17
>   dctech tech technology",
>   "url_m"=>"https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4583/38280904752_abe0b93180.jpg", "height_m"=>"333", "width_m"=>"500"},  {"id"=>"38312540901",
>   "owner"=>"131718287@N07", "secret"=>"7b6e6805d4", "server"=>"4568",
>   "farm"=>5, "title"=>"IMG_3458", "ispublic"=>1, "isfriend"=>0,
>   "isfamily"=>0, "count_comments"=>"0", "tags"=>"washington post dc web
>   women codeher17 dctech tech technology",
>   "url_m"=>"https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4568/38312540901_7b6e6805d4.jpg", "height_m"=>"500", "width_m"=>"333"},  {"id"=>"38281453252",
>   "owner"=>"131718287@N07", "secret"=>"438293cffd", "server"=>"4539",
>   "farm"=>5, "title"=>"IMG_3460", "ispublic"=>1, "isfriend"=>0,
>   "isfamily"=>0, "count_comments"=>"0", "tags"=>"washington post dc web
>   women codeher17 dctech tech technology",
>   "url_m"=>"https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4539/38281453252_438293cffd.jpg", "height_m"=>"333", "width_m"=>"500"}

Why is throwing this error?

Comment: You need `photo.count_comments.to_i * -1`. The error message is saying that the method `String#*` requires a non-negative argument. For example, `"cat" * 3  #=> "catcatcat"`. A negative argument (instead of `3`) would make no sense here.

Comment: If you look at the almost-raw data you'll see `"count_comments"=>"0"` so `count_comments` is a string. Seems a bit odd but there you go.

Answer (score -1):

`count_comments` is a string, so you should convert it to a number first. In the process you can also eliminate the multiplication altogether.

```
def rank_photos(photos)
  photos.sort_by { |photo| -photo.count_comments.to_i }
end
```